# How to emulate a Timeout property?

Tags: rest, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a call to a remote Datasnap REST method where the server sometimes doesn't respond and I need to detect it and terminate the application instead of leaving it frozen.

I use a DSRestConnection, and a Datasnap REST Client Module where all the remote methods are defined, attached to the DSRestConnection. I can't find a Timeout property on them, AFAIK I can only set Timeouts on the Datasnap Server, but sometimes the client loses connection to the server, so I also need to raise a Timeout on the client.

How can I emulate a Timeout when I don't have one ?. Is there a class to help do that or do I need to code it from the ground up ?. in this case, the way to go is to do the remote call on a secondary threat, so the main thread is still responsive and use something like a Timer to check if the call has succeeded in time ?.

I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Is this on a LAN or WAN?  On a LAN, with its lower latency, etc, a simpler way that detecting the timeout is to "pulse" the server from a background thread, possibly running the same server machine.

Comment: Hi Martyn, thanks for answering. No, it's a WAN call (the Datasnap REST Server is hosted on Amazon's cloud). What do you mean "pulsing the server".

Comment: Pulsing?  Oh, just calling some low-overhead method of the server at regular intervals to see whether you get a response.  It's not a perfect test, of course, but you can detect that the server isn't responding faster than if you wait on a timeout of the method you are really interested in.

Comment: @MarcGuillot sorry, I misread (deleted my comment)

Comment: @MartynA I see, it's a good suggestion, thanks. it won't work for me this time, because I don't have that client app permanently open, it just starts the moment there is new data to send, and closes after that.

Comment: No worries.  I'm glad @UweRaabe has come to the rescue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TDSRestConnection` should give you access to the underlying `TDSHTTP` client via its *HTTP* property. The `TDSHTTP` client exposes a *ConnectTimeout* and a *ReadTimeout* property. Perhaps the latter one is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that would be perfect. I'm creating a second thread to unfreeze the application but I don't manage to get it working, it would be perfect if I can avoid it. I'm going to try it now.